# Finding a path in a 2d grid and returning all matched nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph, multidimensional-array, path-finding, graph-traversal

Say I have an rows*columns grid, and each node on the grid has an integer (state) value.

```
state[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS]
```

If the value of

`state[row][0] == state[row][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS -1]`

I want to check if there is a "path" consisting of only the same state from these two points..

By path, I mean the state to the left, right, bottom, or top is the same as the origin state.

I'm not sure if it matters, but lets say the state is binary (# or -)  So if I'm checking for a path of state == "-", we can continue the path if the state to the N,E,S,W is also == "-"

The end row must equal the start row.

Examples of success:

```
|# # # # #|    
|# # # # #|    
|# # # # #|
|- # # # #|
|- - - - -|
```

or

```
|# # # # #|
|# # # - #|
|# - - - #|
|- - # - -|
|# # # - -|
```

or

```
|# # # # #|
|# # # - #|
|# # # - #|
|- - - - #|
|- # # - -|
```

Examples of fail:

```
|# # # # #|
|# # # # #|
|# # # # #|
|- - - - #|
|# # - - -|
```

or

```
|# # # # #|
|# # # - #|
|# # # - #|
|# - - - #|
|- # # - #|
```

or

```
|# # # # #|
|# # - # #|
|# # # # #|
|# - # - #|
|- # - # -|
```

would fail.

How do I do this?  I code in Objective C, but pseudo code to help me understand the steps will be sufficient.

Besides checking for the BOOL existence of a path, I'd want to return an array of all grid coordinate in the path..

Is this easy to implement or am I in way over my head?

Comment: Just to clarify: does the path have to start and end in the same row? Or just "you can get from column 0 to the last column whilst only ever touching a node with value 1, and stepping to adjacent nodes either vertically, or horizontally"? Might be worth clarifying question a bit, and maybe even highlighting the "good" path found in your first example.

Comment: In the first example does it pass because |0 1 1 1 0| ?

Comment: What exactly is a path.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are solving a maze - in which case you will find http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/alg/maze/ helpful. Since you actually need to tell this algorithm what the start and end points are, you would pass "any element with 1 in the first column" as possible starting point, and "any element with 1 in the final column" as possible end point.

Comment: whao, I think I understood the question. I should get bonus points for that. (just assume for example that you are in a game where 0 is the background and 1 are walls, and you want to go from left to right by only moving up, down right or left ; if you managed, then assume the opposite : you're in a game where 0 are the walls and 1's are the background and do the same. In the second example you can't go from the left of the 5th row to the right of the 5th row by only following zeros).

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity - how do I highlight stuff?

Comment: A path is when adjacent (north south east or west, not diagnoal) has the same value as the source.

Comment: The constraint is that the row value at column 0 must equal the row value at the last column..  I'm actually iterating these over a circle, didn't show it in these examples but the last column would be always identical to the first... so actually state[row][column-2] must equal state[row][0] too - but state[row+-1][column-2] not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks Floris I'm looking at that maze link now.

Comment: BTW the first fail example actually looks like a succes to me.

Comment: @ wildplasser - first thanks for fixing the format!!  I couldn't figure out how to do it.  Second, the first fail example is not valid because the value in column 0 != column 4 (the first and last column must be the same

Comment: The reason is that this is actually a square grid that i'm representing as a circle, and I'm checking for "rings" - so the board I test the path for is a copy of the actual board where I readd the first column as the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the solution that worked from me - based off the maze solving algorithm linked to by @Floris.

There may be a bug or two, and it's certainly not optimized, but it works for now.

Should be pretty easy to follow, thanks for everyone's help:

```
-(BoardState)solutionPathExistsForColor {
    //create a board copy where the last column equals the first

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_ROWS+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_COLUMNS+1; j++) {
            if (j == BOARD_COLUMNS) {
                loopedBoard[i][j] = landed[i][0];
            } else {
                loopedBoard[i][j] = landed[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (BoardState state = 1; state < kBoardStateCount; state++) {
        //first check if it is possible there is a path


        //for each row
        for (int row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++) {

            //set solution path to zero
            for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_ROWS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_COLUMNS; j++) {
                    solutionPath[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
            BOOL aTest = [self findPathToGoalRow:row //iterate
                                   andGoalColumn:BOARD_COLUMNS  //always the same
                                         fromRow:row  //iterate
                                       andColumn:0  // always the same
                                         ofState:state]; //iterate
            if (aTest) {
                CCLOG(@"Success! State %i", (int)state);
                //now that you know a path exists, modify the path to contain all correct adjacent cells
                [self fixSolutionPathOfColor:state];
                return state;
            } else {
                CCLOG(@"Failure!");
            }
        }
    }
    return kBoardStateVOID;
}

-(BOOL)findPathToGoalRow:(int)goalRow
           andGoalColumn:(int)goalColumn
                 fromRow:(int)fromRow
               andColumn:(int)fromColumn
                 ofState:(BoardState)state {


    //check to see if we've already seen this row and column
    if (solutionPath[fromRow][fromColumn] == 1) {
        return NO;
    }

//  if (x,y outside maze) return false
    if (fromRow > BOARD_ROWS -1 || fromColumn > BOARD_COLUMNS || fromRow < 0 || fromColumn < 0) {
        return NO;
    }
//  if (x,y is goal) return true
    if (fromRow == goalRow && fromColumn == goalColumn) {
        return YES;
    }
//  if (x,y not open) return false
    //if ([self boardStateAtRow:fromRow andColumn:fromColumn] != state) {
    if (loopedBoard[fromRow][fromColumn]!=state) {
        return NO;
    }


//  mark x,y as part of solution path
    solutionPath[fromRow][fromColumn] = 1;

//  if (FIND-PATH(North of x,y) == true) return true
    if ([self findPathToGoalRow:goalRow
                  andGoalColumn:goalColumn
                        fromRow:fromRow+1
                      andColumn:fromColumn
                        ofState:state]) {
        return YES;
    }
//  if (FIND-PATH(East of x,y) == true) return true
    if ([self findPathToGoalRow:goalRow
                  andGoalColumn:goalColumn
                        fromRow:fromRow
                      andColumn:fromColumn+1
                        ofState:state]) {
        return YES;
    }
//  if (FIND-PATH(South of x,y) == true) return true
    if ([self findPathToGoalRow:goalRow
                  andGoalColumn:goalColumn
                        fromRow:fromRow-1
                      andColumn:fromColumn
                        ofState:state]) {
        return YES;
    }
//  if (FIND-PATH(West of x,y) == true) return true
    if ([self findPathToGoalRow:goalRow
                  andGoalColumn:goalColumn
                        fromRow:fromRow
                      andColumn:fromColumn-1
                        ofState:state]) {
        return YES;
    }
//  unmark x,y as part of solution path
    solutionPath[fromRow][fromColumn] = 0;
    return NO;
}

-(void)fixSolutionPathOfColor:(BoardState)color {

    for (int column = 0; column < BOARD_COLUMNS; column++) {
        BOOL bottomColumnOfSolutionPathFound = NO;
        int checkingRow = 0;
        while (!bottomColumnOfSolutionPathFound) {
            if ([self solutionCellAtRow:checkingRow andColumn:column] == 1) {
                bottomColumnOfSolutionPathFound = YES;
            } else {
                checkingRow++;
            }
        }

        //you'll start with this bottom row and look below
        if (solutionPath[checkingRow][column] == 1) {
            int nextRowToCheck = checkingRow-1;
            BOOL keepChecking = YES;
            while (nextRowToCheck >= 0 && keepChecking) {
                if ([self boardStateAtRow:(nextRowToCheck) andColumn:column] == color) {
                    if ([self solutionCellAtRow:(nextRowToCheck) andColumn:column] != YES) {
                        solutionPath[nextRowToCheck][column] = 1;
                    }
                    nextRowToCheck--;
                } else {
                    keepChecking = NO;
                }
            }
            //now repeat for above
            nextRowToCheck = checkingRow+1;
            keepChecking = YES;
            while (nextRowToCheck < BOARD_ROWS && keepChecking) {
                if ([self boardStateAtRow:(nextRowToCheck) andColumn:column] == color) {
                    if ([self solutionCellAtRow:(nextRowToCheck) andColumn:column] != YES) {
                        solutionPath[nextRowToCheck][column] = 1;
                    }
                    nextRowToCheck++;
                } else {
                    keepChecking = NO;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just wrote up a blog post about this (and my new game, Floris).  http://oxandcoon.com/blog/2013/4/14/floris-etymology

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking at a specific case of a very common general programming problem. Your grid is a specific type of graph; each cell is a node which may be connected to adjacent nodes. Start by looking at the simplest [graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal) strategies; a breadth-first or depth-first search. Those two algorithms are simple tools you should be familiar with and problem all you need to solve this specific problem.
In your case you could restrict the search to only be able to explore nodes containing equal values to the current node and see if you are able to reach your destination.

Now either of those algorithms will tell you if a path exists. That's a good start but what if you want to find the *shortest* path? For that we have [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_Algorithm).

That's pretty good but we still have to traverse the entire graph to find the shortest path. Not a problem if the graph is small but as it grows that is going to become an expensive operation. Is there some way we can find the shortest path without searching everywhere? There is: take a look at the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) ("A star") algorithm.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not actually in need of the shortest path, more like a flood fill of a possible path - so it might be something like first determine if it is possible that a path exists.  Then find if a path exists.  Then flood fill (but not fill anything) to return all the locations of the path (and the neighboring locations that also match the state of the path)  christ this is hard to explain!